# Site removing www from address in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, htaccess

I want that user can access my site with or without www.But it didn't work with wwww.
My site removing www from address and redirect to non www address like http://example.co.uk.I write this code in htaccess for www but didn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^babycave.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.babycave.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can any body guide me where the issue is ? from admin side i setted secure and unsecure url's like `http://babycave.co.uk/`.Thanks

Below is my htaccess file:

```
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^babycave.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.babycave.co.uk$1 [R=301]

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Have you checked your core_config_data table ? Check what is the base URL in there. You need to write the base URL as `http://www.example.com`

Comment: yes i checked and changed the secure and unsecure url to `http://www.example.com`.check comments btwn me and Su123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue from plesk panel.
In `Plesk admin -> domain -> "Hosting Settings"` goto the option `Preffered Domain`.

The default option in my setup is `"domain.tld"`. I change it to `"www.domain.tld"` and then change database secure and unsecure paths to `http://www.example.com` in core_config_Data table.If you didn't change anyone of them then it will show redirect loop error.No need to change htaccess for this.Thanks all of you

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^babycave.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.babycave.co.uk$1 [R=301]
```

EDIT:

Go to table core_config_data

Update these values to new URL

```
web/secure/base_url //(new url)
web/unsecure/base_url // (new url)
```

Empty the `var` folder.

Comment: Sorry this error "This webpage has a redirect loop".I am pasting my htaccess file in question area so one can get idea where i goes wrong.

Comment: Edited the answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: you mean that i will change the secure and unsecure url to www.babycav.co.uk then it will work ?

Comment: yes. then clear the cash as well

Comment: Not working same issue you can check online.

Comment: did you changed the above mentioned URLs in core_config_data table?

Comment: yes i changed and remove the cache but still same error of redirect loop.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: check on your browser now.Not work for me

Comment: Earlier it was loaded. Now it's not.  The issue is because of your .htaccess file or your cache folder.Place a new copy of .htaccess from a fresh magento package and do the above mentioned modifications. Then delete the cache and session folders as well.
Then refresh.

Comment: Done just like you say.still same .please have look in browser.thanks

Comment: Can you compare the above two lines with your .htaccess file's relevant lines?

Comment: you can view my htaccess with your lines.i just edit my question with latest htaccess.

Comment: And one thing more i just change "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to 301.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the result!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!babycave.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.babycave.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Alternate ( Virtual Host )**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAlias babycave.co.uk
   RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.babycave.co.uk/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName babycave.co.uk
  Redirect permanent / http://www.babycave.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but didn't work.Redirect www to non www.

Comment: Mahmud, is it possible to use this rewrite rules in the vhost config instead of .htaccess? I will give you an other alternative!

Comment: I have no idea but we can try.

Comment: Mahmud, try edited post please! Also, don't forget to remove above rules from .htaccess to be able to eliminate rule conflict.

Comment: Do i add virtual host code to htaccess ?

Comment: Just add in virtual host config or if you have only one apache config file, put there. But don't forget to remove from .htaccess. And, restart the apache!

Comment: Sorry not get you all.I have only directory access where my magento files are hosted.can you guide me little bit where the file will be on server ?

Comment: Mahmud, are you using dedicated or VPS server? And what kind of OS, linux or windows!

Comment: I am using Parallels Plesk Panel for the site hosting.

Comment: Then, you can't use SSH, sorry but I have no information about Plesk and never used.